# Preserving a hard disk, plugged or unplugged from power?

Tags: hard-drive, storage

We have a few hard disks we use as data backup. We keep them in a cool store room until they are needed (we manually copy data into them). These data aren't exactly critical, we won't shed a single tear if it were to fail but that's another story.

I've heard from the internet that unused hard disks tend to clog, the oil in their spindle becomes sticky and will eventually stop working.

Would you say it would be better to keep them plugged into a computer even though there is no I/O operation?

Comment: Well I suppose the heat in the system would help keep the oil in a liquid state. And while electronics don’t like heat, unless your system’s insides are getting as hot as an oven, then the heat isn’t going to harm the static, offline drive.

Comment: In general, unplugged.  Ideally they should be fired up and run for 30 minutes or so every few months, but keeping them constantly spinning would be a bad idea.

Comment: `In general, unplugged. Ideally they should be fired up and run for 30 minutes or so every few months` Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, IME, that would be "things from the internet that were true-ish, 20 years ago" but are misleading to perpetuate now.

Unplugged. I have several in a safe-deposit box on a rotating basis.